# How to use variable inside the array

Tags: arrays, unix, variables, ksh

I tried to use variable inside an array variable, but its not working as expected.

**CODE**

```
    ENV2[0]=567
    ENV1[0]=123
    ENV1[1]=789
    if [ $1 -eq 1 ]
    then
    name=ENV1
    echo "${name[0]}"
    echo "${name[1]}"
    else
    name=ENV1
    echo "${name[1]}"
    fi
```

**Output**: ENV1
Instead of "123", its printing "ENV1" and a blank line in second echo part. Please help to get the correct output and i am a beginner. Thanks

Comment: what language are you using ? Try name = ENV1[0]

Comment: Hi Rusty009, i am using ksh. i want replace only name=ENV1, becuase i have to list name[0], name[1] instead of declaring one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name=ENV1` will not assign the content of the variable `ENV1` to variable `name`, but the actual string **ENV1** instead.

- To copy the array `ENV1` to `name`, you could use this:

  > `name=$ENV1`

  This is same as `name=${ENV1[0]}`. The first element of the array
  variable will be copied, because the index is not specified. So here,
  only the index 0 is considered.
- To assign all values of `ENV1` to `name`, you should use this:

  > `set -A name "${ENV1[@]}"`

  This sets the array variable `name` to all elements of `ENV1`.

Comment: Thanks amartine, getting blank line for 'echo "${name[1]}"' in both if and else part. Please advise.

Comment: Did you use `set -A name "${ENV1[@]}"` in your code, instead of `name=ENV1`? If so, please let me know your updated code.

Comment: Hi amartine, its working, but when i run the script in debug mode(sh -x name.sh) then is showing error and aborted.
**Error**: name.sh: line 55: set: -A: invalid option
set: usage: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option] [arg ...]

Comment: Hi, you should run it with `ksh -x name.ksh`. sh does not support arrays.